# Python - how to convert string with '+' sign in minutes to datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

How would I convert this string `2019-07-11T00:00+02:00` to datetime? Using this `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S` as format code in `strptime` returns an error. I assume the `+02` is causing this as without it, it will convert to a datetime properly.

```
debut = "2019-07-11T00:00+02:00"
debut_datetime = datetime.strptime(debut, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

Error:

```
raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '2019-07-11T00:00+02:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: How about `datetime.strptime(debut, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:00+%M:%S")`

Comment: @dzakyputra it returns this: `2019-07-11 00:02:00`. Maybe this is correct, but I don't understand why the +02 is there. It would make more sense if the date was `2019-07-11T00:02:00`

Answer (score 1):

When you are defining the `debut_datetime` variable you should change your format parameter in the `.strptime` function. Because datetime is very specific about the format you use, so since you used "00+02", you should change your format to the following:

```
debut_datetime = datetime.strptime(debut, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:00+%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify to:

```
debut = "2019-07-11T00:00+02:00"
debut_datetime = datetime.strptime(debut, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:00+%M:%S")
```